# jquery tablesorter add title/tooltip to show ascending/descending

Tags: jquery, image, sorting, html-table, tablesorter

I am using jquery tablesorter. I have a table like the one here:

http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Except I want the column headers to each have a title/tooltip when they are hovered over with the mouse. For example the default title for first name would be "sort by first name" and then it would change to either "sort ascending first name" or "sort descending first name" and so on for each th. How can I do this since the image is in the css for header image and not set on each th?

```
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown {          background-image: url(desc.gif);  } 
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {          background-image: url(asc.gif);  } 
table.tablesorter thead tr .header {          background-image: url(bg.gif);          background-    repeat: no-repeat;          background-position: center right;          cursor: pointer;  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it... set up a data-title for each header cell with the text you want to add. But instead of saying "by", "ascending" or "descending", we'll use a replacable variable named "{dir}" for direction:

```
<table class="tablesorter">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th data-title="sort {dir} last name">Last</th>
             <th data-title="sort {dir} first name">First</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr><td>Smith</td><td>John</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Jones</td><td>Timothy</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Wong</td><td>Jin</td></tr>
         <tr><td>O'Brien</td><td>Shaun</td></tr>
         <tr><td>Parker</td><td>Peter</td></tr>        
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Then we add a function to go through each table header cell and update the title based on what class name it finds. Call it, and also make sure it is called after each table sort has completed.

```
var table = $('table'),

    updateTitles = function(){
        var t, $this;
        table.find('thead th').each(function(){
            $this = $(this);
            t = "by";
            if ($this.hasClass('headerSortUp')) {
                t = "ascending";
            } else if ($this.hasClass('headerSortDown')) {
                t = "descending";
            }
            $this.attr('title', $this.attr('data-title').replace(/\{dir\}/, t) );
        });
    };

table.tablesorter();

// bind to sort events 
table.bind("sortEnd",function() { 
    updateTitles(); 
});
// set up titles
updateTitles();
```

Here is a[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/9sKwJ/8/).

Comment: your example works great is it possible to add all of this to the function setHeadersCss which is inside of tablesorter.js? It looks like that is where tablesorter is adding and removing the classes

Comment: I wouldn't recommend modifying the actual plugin code unless you can maintain it. If some day in the future you decide to update the plugin, you'll need to remember what changes you made as well as make any modifications needed to get the code working again.

Comment: I am interested in just a simple static `<th data-title="foo">...</th>` working when I use the filter widget. It did not appear to, not in version 2.10.8 anyway. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: @Leonid if you want a static tooltip, change `data-title` to `title`. If that isn't want you want, please open a new question.

Comment: I opened a new question, thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22262325/how-to-create-a-tooltip-for-the-filter-widget-of-the-jquery-tablesorter-plugin

Comment: @Leonid By the way, there is a [header titles widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-header-titles.html) available now.