# Javascript to change title when another column is clicked

Tags: javascript, sorting, html-table, title

I have a table and after a heading in another column is clicked I would like to reset any other columns to say sort by. Currently I have:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
 function changeSort(obj)
 {  

  var firstName = document.getElementById('fName');
 var lastName = document.getElementById('lName');
 var phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phone');
var birthDate = document.getElementById('birth');


if(obj.id == 'fName')
{
//alert("fName");
 obj.title = (obj.title== 'sort ascending first name') ? 'sort descending first 
 name' : 'sort         ascending first name';   
 }

if(obj.id == 'lName')
{
 //alert("lName");
 obj.title = (obj.title== 'sort ascending last name') ? 'sort descending first name' : 'sort   
ascending last name';   
 }

 if(obj.id == 'phone')
  {
  //alert("phone");
  obj.title = (obj.title== 'sort ascending phone number') ? 'sort descending phone  
  number' : 'sort ascending phone number';   
  }

 if(obj.id == 'birth')
 {
  //alert("birth");
   obj.title = (obj.title== 'sort ascending birth date') ? 'sort descending birth      
   date' : 'sort   
  ascending birth date';   
   }   

   }

  </script>
 </head>
 <body

     <table> 

  <tr>
            <th id="fName" onclick='changeSort(this)' title="sort by First Name" >First Name</th>
    <th id="lName" onclick='changeSort(this)' title="sort by Last Name" >Last   
    Name</th>
    <th id="phone" onclick='changeSort(this)' title="sort by Phone Number" >Phone   
   Number</th>
    <th id="birth" onclick='changeSort(this)'title="sort by Birth Date" >Birth   
    Date</th>
    </tr>

   </table>

  </body>
  </html>
```

When I perform a sort on the first column i would like it to change the title to ascending or descending which it currently does but if I decide I would like to sort by last name I want the first name columns title to change back to sort by first name and to not be ascending or descending. How can I get the title of a changed table head to go back to the default when another table head is clciked?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery tablesorter change header title ttributes on sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046715/jquery-tablesorter-change-header-title-ttributes-on-sort)

Comment: possibel duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027508/jquery-tablesorter-add-title-tooltip-to-show-ascending-descending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picking up on André's point that there are cleaner ways, here's the code refactored to make it independent of the number of columns, and otherwise more general.

```
function changeSort(th){
    var titleTemplates = {
        asc:  'sort ascending %s',
        desc: 'sort decending %s',
        dflt: 'sort by %s'
    };
    titleTemplates.get = function(key, txt){
        var t = this[key] || this.dflt;
        return t.replace('%s', txt);
    };
    var headerRow = th.parentNode;
    var cells = headerRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
    for(var i=0; i<cells.length; i++){
        var c = cells[i];
        var s = c.getAttribute('sortCode');
        var s_ = (c !== th) ? '' : (!s || s == 'desc') ? 'asc' : 'desc';
        c.setAttribute('sortCode', s_);
        c.title = titleTemplates.get(s_, c.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

*tested in Opera 11.61*

You could (and really should) go further by attaching the click handler to the TH elements in javascript rather than in the HTML.

Comment: for a micro-optimisation, you could use `for(var i=0, len=cells.length; i<len; i++)`

Comment: didn't work the titles all stayed sort by and never said ascending or descending

Comment: OK, I have made a light edit - changed `th.parentNode()` to `th.parentNode` (I've gotten too used to jQuery; it's a property not a method in native js).

Answer (score 1):

in the end of the function you should add:

```
firstName.title = obj.id == 'fName'? firstName.title : 'sort by first name';
lastName.title = obj.id == 'lName'? lastName.title : 'sort by last name';
phoneNumber.title = obj.id == 'phone'? phoneNumber.title : 'sort by phone number';
birthDate.title = obj.id == 'birth'? birthDate.title : 'sort by birth date';
```

There would be cleaner ways to do this, but we had to refactor the whole code...

Comment: I would add `&&` to the ternary conditions: `obj.id=='fName'&&firstName.title!='sort by first name'`, so it get updated only when necessary (it is not wise to mess with the DOM)

Comment: neither one update the title when another column was clicked they both said ascending not one with sort by and the other with ascending or descenind

Comment: Are u sure you're doing it right? This must be inside thr changeSort function, right at the end

Comment: yes i put it right at the end after the closing bracket for the birth if statement and before the closing bracket for the function

Comment: Oh, can you put it in jsfiddle please?