# How to create a tooltip for the filter widget of the JQuery tablesorter plugin?

Tags: jquery, filter, tablesorter

Possibly related question: [jquery tablesorter add title/tooltip to show ascending/descending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027508/jquery-tablesorter-add-title-tooltip-to-show-ascending-descending)

Below is HTML that I tried:

```
<table class="tablesorter" id="table1">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th title="this is title for the header" data-title="I want this to be title for the filter">Column1</th>
             <th title="this is title for the header" data-title="I want this to be title for the filter">Column2</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
         <tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

And the JS:

```
$('#table1').tablesorter({
    theme : 'ice',
    cssInfoBlock : 'tablesorter-no-sort',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'stickyHeaders', 'filter']
});
```

The title portion works. What I do not gte is a mouseover text over the filter text box. I do not want to intercept those events manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better to add a placeholder to the filter using a `data-placeholder` attribute on the table header ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/2180/))

```
<th data-placeholder="Search Alphanumeric">AlphaNumeric</th>
```

But if you truly want a tooltip to appear, then try this code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/2181/)):

HTML

```
<th data-filter-title="Search Alphanumeric">AlphaNumeric</th>
```

Script

```
$('table')
    .on('filterInit', function() {
        var c = this.config;
        c.$headers.each(function(i){
            c.$filters.eq(i).attr( 'title', $(this).attr('data-filter-title') );
        });
    })
    .tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter']
    });
```

Comment: Ok, I was aware of that option and was experimenting with it. By the way, your library is great! The reason why I did ask this is: I am displaying a table of data to a very non-technical audience. They wanted Excel-like ability for filtering which the filter widget provides, but there is a tiny price to pay - learning the mini language for filtering. For example, it was reported to me as a bug that entering 80 matched both 80 and 580 whereas they should have used  =80. I suggested that we link to your docs but that was considered too heavy.

Comment: A pop-up dialog explaining all of the options was also rejected as too heavy. We are trying to experiment with a combination of a placeholder and a tooltip, and you have provided a working example - thank you! I just wanted to point out to you that novice users do not immediately know what all of the options are - what should be the best way to let them discover it? Some columns do have the same type of data, so ideally I would just restrict the things that users can do with it. All of the options are still vast. Excel discovers data type and provides a bunch of menus. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Maybe it would be better for non-technical users to have a [slider for numeric columns](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter-formatter-1.html) and a select for text columns? I don't know what kind of data is contained within your table, but the filter functions allow customizing selects for each column.

Comment: I have seen the slider examples. It is a good start but the UI is still not perfect IMO. Doing an equivalent of =80 using a two-sided slider requires moving both exactly. In the case of floats rather than integers this becomes a real pain. It takes some thought to figure out that "between filter" defaults to no filtering by virtue of having min at min and max at max. Hence, one can express just <= using between but it is not immediately obvious, IMO. There does not seem to be a great non-ugly way to cram every possible num filter feature into a slider or a slider-like control. This Q is answrd